# OpenCV memory management of cv::Mat

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-management, mat

I am quite new to OpenCV and having some memory leaks in my application, due to cv::Mat usage. If I use a Mat as follows:

```
cv::Mat mat = matProducingFunctionFoo();
```

How can I free the memory after I am done with mat object. I know (from other posts) if I use create function or constructors with size and type parameters, I can call for the release function of the mat. However here I am not certain about the size or type of the mat, so it is dynamic. How can I free the memory (release is not working in this case)?

Comment: You don't have to worry about that, since Mat will be automatically released. Unless you're using Mat* you're safe. In general, you never have to use create or release, just use constructors. If you post an example of the leak we can provide more details

Comment: Thank you Miki, i have read about that. Mat has its own memory management. However the app has a constant memory growth. Because memory covered by the mat is not freed the moment scope has been exited:( when i place a breakpoint and wait for few minutes i see a huge increase in the amount of free memory... I am looking for a way to make this happen more frequently in real time...

Comment: _memory covered by the mat_ ... If you're using a `Mat` to wrap a, say, `uchar*` containing data allocated somewhere else, then the `Mat` doesn't owns the data, and won't release it. In this case it just offers a view of the data. You need to release those data by yourself